# tengo problemas con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

buen dia! tengo un problema con bootstrap[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como puden ver tengo 3 Problemas, uno que no logro hacer que esos 2 div's tengan el mismo "height" (el slideshow y la parte derecha que es un tab), segundo en mi tab de la derecha, pongo las imagenes responsive con bootstrap para q pues se adapten pero miren! se salen del div!que puedo hacer? y como puedo pegar la la imagen al borde de mi div? en ela parte izquierda...

lo tengo asi

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" id="service1">
    aqui tengo el slider...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="service1">
    <div class="tab">
  <div class="cont_tab">
      <div class="col-md-6 imag">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/sect1/L1.jpg" alt="Servicio1" title="Servicio 1">
   </div>
      <div class="cont_descripcion col-md-6">
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="OpenService(event,'service1')">Servicio 1</button>
   <p class="descripcion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                  </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A manera de observación sin atacar el problema, creo que tiene que corregir los ids de los div, ambos se llaman "service1"

Answer (score 1):

La clase `row-eq-height` en el row principal debería solucionarlo así:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-9" id="service1">
        aqui tengo el slider...
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" id="service1">

        <div class="tab">
            <div class="cont_tab">
                <div class="col-md-6 imag">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/sect1/L1.jpg" alt="Servicio1" title="Servicio 1">
                </div>
                <div class="cont_descripcion col-md-6">
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="OpenService(event,'service1')">Servicio 1</button>
                    <p class="descripcion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Puede consultar la documentación de manera más extensa [aquí](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/):